# How to debug asp.net error after page_unload - Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, debugging, global-asax, dropdownbox

vb.net with a masterpage and many user controls. we're building a lot of dynamic controls including dropdownlists. Immediately after Page_Unload event is complete, this error is thrown then caught in the global.asax Application_Error method.

"Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList"

The stack trace isn't telling me anything useful about what control is actually causing this. How can I debug? If I step through the entire page sequence while debugging, I get to the end of the page_unload event, and the error is immediately thrown/caught in the global.asax:

The stack is:

```
Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.
 Category:    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.VerifyMultiSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at ASP.productsearch_aspx.__RenderpnlGrid(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.RenderFormCallback(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control containerControl)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.HtmlFormWrapper.System.Web.UI.IHtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.RenderPageCallback(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control pageControl)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a break for `System.Web.HttpException` (there is a Find... button in the exceptions dialog http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h22dk1y6.aspx). After applying this setting the debugger should stop when the exception is thrown (inside `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.VerifyMultiSelect` method). In the watch window you should be able to evaluate `this` and check to which control it refers.

Comment: thanks, but this didn't help. I made sure that exceptions for System.Web.HttpException are caught, but the debugger only catches it if I have a breakpoint in global.asax - application_Error(). by then, the detail it gives me is what I have pasted above.

Comment: Make sure that in Debugging options in VS "Just my code" checkbox is unchecked and try again.